# Simplifying an algorithm with matrix algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, covariance, outer-product

Sorry in advances for my lack of knowledge on this topic.

Given a $p$ by $p$ positive semidefinite matrix $S$ from which, I want to compute this algorithm

```
for (i in 1:p){
for (j in 1:p){
Target[i,j] = S[i,j]*S[j,i]+S[i,i]*S[j,j]
}
}
```

is there a better efficient way using matrix algebra?

Comment: All it seems like you're doing is multiplying two pairs of numbers and adding them together. I'm not sure what would possibly be simpler than that. Are you looking for a simple way to express the new matrix as a whole in terms of $S$?

Comment: Yes, it's that! Sorry if i'm unclear.

Comment: Notice that target matrix $T$ is symmetric, $T_{i,j}=T_{j,i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)), we could write
$$
T = S \circ S^T + \operatorname{diag}(S)\operatorname{diag}(S)^T,
$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(S)$ is the column-vector $(S_{1,1},\dots,S_{p,p})$.